# Understanding Python Dictionaries

Tags: python

Could someone explain how Python understands this `key` variable? If `key` is not defined anywhere else, why does this work?

```
tweet = {}
tweet['text'] = "#Python rocks!"
tweet['id'] = 1293827492

tweet['user'] = {}
tweet['user']['screen_name'] = "Linus__Torvalds"
tweet['user']['id'] = 829817283

tweet['media'] = {}
tweet['media']['hashtags'] = ["#Python"]

for key in tweet:
    print "%s => %s" % (key, tweet[key])
```

I've seen the `key` variable changed to other things as well (e.g. `dict_key`) to make it more readable, however I still don't grasp how Python understands what I'm asking it parse when it gets to the print line. How does it know what `key` and `tweet[key]` actually are?

Comment: Because *you've told it?* `for key in tweet:` is iterating over the keys of the dictionary in the same way that `for thing in [1, 2, 3]:` is iterating over the elements in the list; with any `for` loop, Python assigns each item in the iterable, in turn, to the loop variable, then runs the nested block. Also note that your example seems to be missing a closing quote, hence the weird formatting.

Comment: There are at least 3 closing quotes missing. If you could fix those, it would be a start.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, I could put whatever in my _for_ loop and it will just store everything in there and iterate it as I tell it to?

For example I could write (code in imgur link)

https://imgur.com/a/tGEPd

And it would return something like Desert => Rattlesnake? 
(I get a TypeError with that code but I can work on it)

Comment: You could do `for key, value in your_dictionary.items():`. Then you get the key **and** the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop is a kind of assignment: `for x in y: ...` works by getting an iterator for `y`, then repeating the body of the loop for each element returned by the iterator, after assigning it to `x`.

An iterator for a `dict` simply returns the keys, so given your `dict` defined by

```
tweet = {}
tweet['text'] = "#Python rocks!"
tweet['id'] = 1293827492

tweet['user'] = {}
tweet['user']['screen_name'] = "Linus__Torvalds"
tweet['user']['id'] = 829817283

tweet['media'] = {}
tweet['media']['hashtags'] = ["#Python"]
```

the `for` loop is equivalent to

```
key = 'text'
print "%s => %s" % (key, tweet[key])
key = 'id'
print "%s => %s" % (key, tweet[key])
key = 'user'
print "%s => %s" % (key, tweet[key])
key = 'media'
print "%s => %s" % (key, tweet[key])
```

You can also think of the `for` loop as an optimized version of the following `while` loop, in which you need to work with the iterator explicitly:

```
i = iter(tweet)
while True:
    try:
        key = next(i)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print "%s => %s" % (key, tweet[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the tutorial [section on dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  (Reading everything before that would be good too.) Then read the first example in the following section, which is similar to your code.  (And I would recommend changing your code to follow the example, except use `value` instead of `v`.

You can use any name you want for the target name, which repeatedly gets bound to objects yielded by the iterable.  You used `key`, with is a standard name for a dict key.  I don't think that `dict_key` is any better.

In your code, the name `key` is bound to a different key, such as `id`, `media`, or `text`, in no particular order, each iteration.  The name binding is like doing an assigment statement, `key = 'id'`, or whatever.  I hope this helps.